# Simplifying code with LINQ (Collections within collections)

Tags: linq-to-objects, simplify

Given an object graph that looks something like the following;

```
A --> B[] --> B1[]
          --> B2[]   
  --> C[]
```

I need to check certain conditions on members/properties of B1 and B2 as well as ensuring that b2.Code appears somewhere within the C[]. If all conditions are satisfied, I then need to construct a new object using variables from elements of the C and B array. My current attempt is shown below, but I am wondering if this could be made more concise with LINQ?

```
   A a = GetA();
   List<MyTest> tsts = new List<MyTest>();
   foreach (B b in a.B)
    {
        foreach (B1 b1 in b.B1)
        {
            if (b1.State == ("READY"))
            {
                foreach (B2 b2 in b.B2)
                {
                    var tst = (from c in a.C
                           where c.Code == b2.Code && !c.IsRedundant
                           select new MyTest
                           {
                               Code = c.Code,
                               BVal = b.BVal,
                               C1Val = c.C1                     
                           }).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (tst != null)
                        tsts.Add(tst);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. Basically each new `foreach` roughly equates to an extra `from` clause:

```
var tests = from b in GetA().B
            from b1 in b.B1
            where b1.State == "READY"
            from b2 in b.B2.Take(1)
            from c in a.C
                       .Where(x => x.Code == b2.Code && !c.IsRedundant)
                       .Take(1)
            select new MyTest
            {
                Code = c.Code,
                BVal = b.BVal,
                C1Val = c.C1                     
            };

var testList = tests.ToList();
```

A few notes on this:

- It seems odd that you're never actually using `b1`, but you'll create an extra set of tests for each `b1` which is in the "ready" state.
- The unconditional `break` within the `foreach (B2 b2 ...)` loop basically means we only ever execute the loop body once - hence the `Take(1)`
- The way you only use the first result of the innermost query is why I've got the inner query (expressed through extension methods) with a `Take(1)` call to get at most one result

It's quite possible that some of these oddities can be removed - but it's not clear what you're really trying to achieve, so I've just tried to make the code reproduce your original query as faithfully as possible.

Comment: Thanks for this. It really looks promising.
I may have been a little hasty in posting my code with regards to the oddities, but to address your notes;
 - We never actually take anything from b1, however we don't want to add to our list if b1.State is not "READY"
 - The FirstOrDefault and break are used as there should only ever be 0 or 1 matching x.Code == b2.Code. Therefore, if there is a match, we'll use it, otherwise, we should **really** carry on processing the next item in my outermost loop (ie. b). Typically, there are at most 2 elements in the b1 array so I did without a break.